# Computer booting into "grub rescue"

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grubrescue

I tried writing a .img file to an existing partition (the partition that my computer boots  into). When I rebooted my computer it booted to "GRUB Rescue" and said "Unknown filesystem". I tried changing the BIOS and plugging in a USB but it didn't work.

This is my main computer and I really need help. I screwed up *big time*.

Comment: When I attempted `insmod normal` I got this error: ```error: symbol `grub_file_filters_all' not found.```.

Comment: `insmod normal` didn't solve the problem of user53817 who asked the linked question either, but Boot-Repair did solve the problem as mentioned in UPDATE 5 at the end of the question.